# Tried starting with qt however I can't "make" the simple example

Tags: c++, qt

today I wanted to try qt for the first time and followed this guide: "http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html"

Then in the very first code example I tried to do the same. Here's the example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argv, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argv, args);

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Well I directly failed to include QApplication and QTextEdit. So I replaced it with the path to the file(/usr/include/qt/QtGui/QApplication). Then I get this error:

```
g++ -c -pipe -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -I. -o test.o test.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QTextEdit:1:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qtextedit.h:45:39: grave Error occured: QtGui/qabstractscrollarea.h: File or directory not found.
 #include <QtGui/qabstractscrollarea.h>
                                       ^
compilation finished.
Makefile:728: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

any idea what I should do?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Edit: I totally forgot that parts of the error message were in german - fixed that

Edit2: In QtCreator it works, but not on command line, which I'd love get working!

Comment: Did you use qmake? Or you're using Qt Creator?

Comment: And what is the error message in English? Not everyone here can read German.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg clearly missing include file. Quick look and you can see that compile line has paths to /usr/include/qt and file that is reporting error is in /usr/include/qt4/ path. Looks like user3218071 did not install some developer packages and tried to replace them on his/her own

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry fixed that, now it should be in english

Comment: @KamilKlimek I used qmake -project, qmake and in the end make. I wrote it in vim, so I used the command line to compile the project. However QtCreator is installed, so shouldn't the files be installed anyway(with QtCreator?)

Comment: QtCreator may use it's own paths. What SO you're using? Ubuntu? If you do then try to install all qt*-dev packages

Comment: Also did you install Qt some other way? Did you install QtCreator from web page? Or from OS package repository?

Comment: I'm using arch linux and I'm pretty sure that I have all the packages installed :/
I installed QtCreator and Qt both from the official repository

Comment: You have broken configuration somwhere as I said. Your current qmake from console expects Qt to be in /usr/include/qt/* directory but it is present in /usr/include/qt4/. You must investigate further with your OS and it's repository. What does qmake -version print in console?

Comment: Using Qt version 5.2.0 in /usr/lib

Comment: So here is your problem. You're using qt5 in console and qt4 in QtCreator

Comment: Hm, and how could I change this?

Comment: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/35355 - someone met same problem with arch